# Dynamically disabling/omitting Apache configuration directives (DRY)

Tags: apache, apache2, ssl-certificate, dry, vhosts

I am working on a product that runs Apache, and i'm trying to make the configuration more DRY — right now there are many different vhost configs that get loaded in different situations but are 90% identical, and this is very tedious to deal with when a change needs made. I don't think Apache is really designed with this kind of dynamic environment in mind, but w/e, here i am anyway.

So i've first turned to environment variables — i have a small boot-strap script that determines the necessary configuration and dumps variables into `/etc/apache2/envvars` (which is loaded by `apache2ctl` and similar on Ubuntu). This allows me to do things like this:

`envvars`:

```
export    MYKEY='/path/to/mykey'
export   MYCERT='/path/to/mycert'
export MYBUNDLE='/path/to/mybundle'
```

vhost config:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile ${MYKEY}
SSLCertificateFile    ${MYCERT}
SSLCACertificateFile  ${MYBUNDLE}
```

This works fine, but only as long as `MYKEY`, &al., are non-empty variables referencing non-empty files. In some configurations, for example, no CA bundle is required, so i tried just pointing `MYBUNDLE` to `/dev/null`. Apache considers this a 'syntax error' because `/dev/null` is an empty file, and refuses to start.

My question: Is there any way i can dynamically disable/omit configuration directives in the Apache config (based on environment variables or a similar mechanism) without having to maintain separate files for each possible scenario?

Alternative question: Is there any way i can provide an empty value/certificate to this particular directive (`SSLCACertificateFile`) in a manner that Apache won't consider invalid?

Ubuntu 12.04.5
Apache 2.2.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you want is a management tool for your configuration.

Now I'm not sure how often you deploy but you probably could make a script that generates your templates for you?

If you have a greater need, maybe consider automation software and use some kind of template? I'm thinking something like chef (https://www.chef.io/)  or puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/) or ... They all support template and you can provide value based on environment / server / moods for the different values.

Comment: These are not servers being deployed to but rather network devices in the possession of customers which are re-configured locally and dynamically based on their (limited) input. I have some experience with Ansible, i could certainly use something like that. But that's a big change to the way our config system works, whereas an Apache solution would not be. I will probably accept your answer though, i imagine i won't receive a perfect easy answer. Cheers

Comment: Oh, there is probably something you could do... Split each section in a different file and reuse it using include. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#include